# How to access expired domain website hosted on dedicated server without doing any configuration

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, internal-dns, reverse-dns, dns-hosting

I am not sure, this might be a stupid question.
but I would like to know if that is possible. and any website available from where I can do this online.

One of my website is hosted on server i.e. xxx.xxx.xx.xxx shared ip address. 
My domain is expired or i don't have domain for that website. but server is live and accessible.

When I configure my local computer HOST file and following

mywebsitename.com xxx.xxx.xx.xxx (server ip where site hosted.)

Now I can open the website by typing the above url.

Is there a way or is there a website which can do this for me. 
where I enter the websitename and my dedicated server ip and it can show the website hosted on that server, without doing any configuration on my computer or on remote server.

I don't know How to access my website from host once my domain is expired. I can't access it using dedicated server ip directly because I need to tell dedicate server which hosted site I want to access.

Any Possibilities????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. DNS servers would have to do this, and at most you could have a company DNS server add the "fake" entry. If anyone could do this for anyone you'd have a million porn sites called "google.com".

Comment: yes. that is valid point. May be I was unable to explain my question. I meant, is there a website who can do this a fake entry on their server/ host file automatically and open my website in a container. so I don't need to add a fake entry in my windows HOST file to access website.

Comment: Only if you're talking about web hosting where your site is a sub-site under their domain, and you don't have any way to use the domain name you want. I.e., google.mydomain.com. But you'll never have google.com again. I think the answer to your question is no, you can't do that outside of your own domain server in your own network so all the machines within your network would see your "domain" but nothing outside will see it.

Comment: If you want your domain to work for others to see it and get to it by name you must actually pay for the domain name and have a DNS server host it on the webbertubes.

Comment: I still unable to explain my question. I have view the website host on my server ip 125.125.25.541 by just adding a line in my HOST file "testwebsite.co.uk 125.125.25.541". OK Now this is is viewable on my computer but none of others. My friend can view same website by adding the same line in his computer host file. Ok Now we both can view the website. none of other. Is there any online website system available where I visit that website i.e.

Comment: and fill up two fields testwebsite.co.uk and ipaddress 125.125.25.541. that website scrip automatically add the above host line in his system and visit that website and fetch the contents to view them in that third party website container so my customer can view the look and feel of website. you know the http://www.archive.org/web/web.php where we enter the website and it take us archive version of that website. that is a built system.

Comment: is there any system available for virtual dns and open the snapshot of website within a website as way back machine.

Comment: No, because you're talking about altering people's systems by visiting a website that will re-point them to a domain that doesn't exist anymore, which if that existed, would be exploited by malware/spammers in a heartbeat. It still sounds like you're describing a way to access your old domain without owning the domain anymore. What you're describing is finding a way to use DNS without using DNS.

Comment: @user57221 You can't do this. Bart has sufficiently explained why. If you still have questions, you should read about DNS, authoritative name servers, and how DNS relates to IP networking. These are all basic Systems Administration concepts. Asking us to explain them in comments is bad because **1)** you should already know it if posting here. This is a site for professionals, after all. **2)** It's too long to explain properly in a comment. **3)** It's well documented in a very large number of places, including other questions on this site.